# Spreadsheet to SQL query generator not working on MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql, google-sheets

I wrote a spreadsheet to SQL query converter just now in JavaScript.  The converter works fine, here is an example of what it spits out:

```
CREATE TABLE something(column1 varchar(3000),column2 varchar(3000),column3 varchar(3000));
INSERT INTO something VALUES(a1,a2,a3);
INSERT INTO something VALUES(b1,b2,b3);
INSERT INTO something VALUES(c1,c2,c3);
```

As far as I can tell, that is a valid SQL query (but maybe I'm wrong...).  When I copy and paste this query into the 'SQL' tab in the MySQL database I created, I get this error message:

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

I thought perhaps it needed the name of the database (`excel`), so I tried adding the name of the database like so:

```
CREATE TABLE excel.something(column1 varchar(3000),column2 varchar(3000),column3 varchar(3000));
INSERT INTO something VALUES(a1,a2,a3);
INSERT INTO something VALUES(b1,b2,b3);
INSERT INTO something VALUES(c1,c2,c3);
```

and I get this:

```
#1142 - CREATE command denied to user '(my SQL information was here but I removed it)' for table 'something'
```

What is it that I'm missing?  I've run other queries directly in MySQL before without issue, but I can't seem to run this CREATE query.  Worst case scenario, I could manually create the table before hand, but that defeats the purpose of automating the process...

Comment: You have to select a database first using `USE yourdatabasename`

Comment: I knew it must have been something simple like this...trying it now.

EDIT: I am still getting an error `#1044 - Access denied for user 'cl21-excel'@'%' to database 'excel' ` when adding `USE excel;` at the beginning of the query.

Comment: @EricDavidSartor It would seem you don't have (create table) access to that database.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson I figured I must, considering I'm using the database from the Cpanel on my hosting account, and I can create tables with the MySQL GUI no problem...but that may be the problem.

Comment: I figured it out.  Really dumb oversight.  I was just putting the query in the wrong place. I needed to click the database name in the left column of MySQL THEN go to the SQL tab.  I was doing it as soon as I entered the MySQL page, which meant it wasn't running in the running place.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `use something;` before your query.

And for your denied access problem do this:

```
GRANT ALL ON something TO user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`